# Is it possible to use shared memory as IPC with galactic windows 10?

Tags: ros2, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

[According to this repository note](https://github.com/ros2/rmw_cyclonedds/blob/master/shared_memory_support.md#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20the%20Shared%20Memory%20feature%20is%20not%20available%20on%20Windows.) it seems that Cyclone DDS does not yet support iceoryx shared memory on windows.

Does any of the other implementations support shared memory on windows?

Thanks in advanced!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391449/is-it-possible-to-use-shared-memory-as-ipc-with-galactic-windows-10?/) by [lora](https://answers.ros.org/users/76693/lora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I found in [ROS Discourse](https://discourse.ros.org/t/dds-performance-comparison-on-windows-for-rmw-providers-in-ros-2/22635) the Fast DDS implementations does.

Now I wonder whether it is possible to use it with python bindings.

---

Originally posted by [lora](https://answers.ros.org/users/76693/lora/) with karma: 26 on 2021-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0